# How to change url from a different component?

Tags: javascript, angular

Current project is on `Angular 6` and I try to make a list of buttons on the left panel like "Ice cream", "Pop corns" etc so when user click on each button then it will change the URL of the add button in the header panel, and when user click on the `Add` button on the header, it supposed to show the create page for the item.

My question is, how to change the URL (or `route`) of `add` button when click on the button on the left panel, as they are from different component?

[image]

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking... What have you tried already? What issues did you have?

Comment: @user184994 thanks I am trying to learn how to dynamically change the route/url of a button (the "Add" on the header panel) when the event is sent from a different component (button from left panel)

Comment: updated the question, sorry about the confusion

Comment: You could use a shared service. The button from the left panel can set the value in the service, and the header panel can read that value when the "add" button is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with something like this:

### wrapper.component.html

```
<app-left-panel #menu> </app-left-panel>
<app-header [selected]="menu.selected"> </app-header>
```

### header.component.ts

```
[...]
export class HeaderComponent{
    @Input() selected;
    [...]
}
```

### header.component.html

```
<!-- something -->
<a [routerLink]="'\/buy\/'+selected">Add</a>
<!-- something else-->
```

### left-panel.component.ts

```
items = ["popcorn","churros","coke"];
[...]
setSelected(value){
    this.selected = value;
}
```

### left-panel.component.html

```
<!--something -->
<button *ngFor="let str of items" (click)="setSelected(str)">{{str}}</button>
<!-- something else -->
```

By doing so you establish a connection between the two components (left-panel and header) inside the wrapper component, which is achieved thanks to the `@Input() selected` element inside your HeaderComponent. As you select each item from the menu, the *Add* button `routerLink` gets updated.